# Getting absolute from relative URLs in CSS files

Tags: javascript, css

A relative URL in a CSS file uses the URL of that CSS file as its base. This is frequently used to specify background images. In Javascript, it's possible to get such relative URLs by parsing the CSS rule for `background-image` (i.e. string the `url` part and removing quotation marks). Now for the question: Is there a way to find the absolute URL that the browser will use, *if the URL of the CSS file is unknown*?

In particular, I need to get the natural dimensions of the background images in question. The usual way to do this is to create an `Image` element, assigning the source URL, waiting for the "load" event and reading the `width`/`height` properties. However, this evidently cannot work for relative URLs, if the CSS files are located in a different directory that the HTML document.

Comment: "if the URL of the CSS file is unknown" How can it be unknown? It should be in `link` tag's `href`.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, but there are several CSS files linked in this particular document, and I cannot know from which one the rule is applied. What I meant is, it is unknown to the JS code that needs to figure out the image dimensions. All it has available is the DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.getComputedStyle(ref_to_element, null).getPropertyValue('background-image');
```

returns an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var ssx=0; ssx<document.styleSheets.length; ssx++){
    var ccss = document.styleSheets[ssx],
        crs = ccss.rules || ccss.cssRules;
    console.log( ccss.href ); // see here - this can be used as reference
    for( var rx=0; rx<crs.length; rx++){
        console.log( crs[rx].cssText ); 
    }
}
```

google:chrome will *always* output absolute URLs, in mozilla:firefox you'll have to use the href and parse the amount of "../" to get to it.